# I can't make nonmanifold wings mesh manifold for 3d print

Tags: 3d-printing

I pulled all of oldschool runescape's meshes so I can 3d print them. They made models with just faces so it's required a lot of work to get some to print but this one eludes me.
Currently I'm working on one of the bosses in the game and got the rest to print flawlessly but separated the wings because it messed the whole print up.

file in question --heads up, it opens quite large on the x&y in blender>>> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hk_TxdC7_Nh3enrIli80tvHG0e4WpoFb

I've used the 3d-print plugin to search for manifolds and 'make manifold' either deletes everything but the flaps of the wings or the spine structure depending on if I've used mesh>normals>recalculate inside/outside or merge by distance.

Any tips would be appreciated though I fear ill have to model from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you already understand what non-manifold geometry is, but if anyone reading this doesn't, there's a good explanation [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry).

I opened up your model, entered edit mode, pressed <kbd>2</kbd> to enter edge select mode, then went to *Select* > *Select All By Trait* > *Non-manifold.* This is what Blender highlighted (its the same for both wings).

[image]

I presume that the complexity of this mesh and the awkwardly placed non-manifold geometry is what is tripping up Blender's algorithm for eliminating that geometry. Let's take a closer look at what exactly going on.

The faces that are highlighted are purely flat planes. Notice how the same face is highlighted when viewing from both sides? You'll need to add thickness to those.

[image]

You'll notice that there are a couple of edges that are highlighted in the center of the wing. In these areas, the faces are coming together down to an edge, a flat edge. Once again, notice how individual edges can be viewed from both sides of the mesh. I've forgotten to deselect a couple edges that are just on the perimeter of your object, but I think you get the point.

[image]

I don't see any quick one press fixes for this... there are multiple non-manifold faces that Blender didn't even highlight, particularly at the base of the wing.

**Edit:**

Alright, I've managed to waterproof the mesh up to the part where it needs to connect to the rest of the body. Waterproofing the mesh was simply a nightmare...Let's just say I had to take apart the mesh and reassemble it, adding in extra edges and faces where necessary.

I wasn't sure how its meant to connect to the rest of the figure (and thus how the mesh should be shaped) so I just left it open there. The bulk of the work is done though, the only open parts of the wings are shown below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm currently trying to help fix it, but I wanted to post that bit first.

Comment: i've only about a weeks of experience on blender but spent 10 hours on this whole model yesterday. I'll be super stoked if you can figure any way around it. Here's a link to the full model i printed after posing and fixing all of its nonmanifold issues 
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WDAUwHNMLyGyiXIV6-jnNMu3iurGyl-f

Comment: @thedwick Alright, more or less fixed up the wing mesh. The process was rather long and convoluted, but the general gist of it was to add extra edges and reconnect the faces to the new edges wherever both sides of the wing came down to a single edge.

Comment: dude thank you so much for the tip!. 3/4 of the bosses in this set have wings with the same problems so now I know what to do with em. Sounds like ill have to figure out a bit more with blender. Thanks again so much!

Comment: @thedwick Oh and here's another tip you ought to hear: There's a difference between the "F" key to fill in gaps, and the "J" key to join vertices. If you took a square plane, selected the two opposite corners and pressed "F", you'd get an extra line that isn't related to the plane at all, but using "J" would split the plane into two. I was looking at the full model and noticed a couple of areas where you had overlapping faces/edges, and I reckon that this is where those came from. Even though those didn't cause any trouble, just somehting to look out for in the future.

Comment: PS: you can download the blend file to see the changes